# Add new schedule to Google Canendar, when the google spreadsheets approved

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is really new user for Google Apps Script.

I would like to make the script that ***when the Google spreadsheet is approved then automatically makes a schedule to Google Calendar.***

But, I just made make a schedule to Google Calendar.
please give me the feedback for the **previous step(when the google spreadsheet is approved)**

```js
function goCreate() {
  /*************************************************/
  /*************************************************/ 
  // This is the script make a schedule from Google Spreadsheet to Google Calendar //
  /*************************************************/
  /*************************************************/
  
  const calID = ""; // 
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calID);                       

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var startDay = ss.getRange("D13").getValue();            //
  var endDay = ss.getRange("G13").getValue();              // 
  var members = ss.getRange("C8:C10").getValues();         // 
  var location = ss.getRange("D14").getValue();            // 
  var description = ss.getRange("D16").getValues();        // 

  if (startDay == endDay){
    eventCal.createAllDayEvent("Test", new Date(startDay)).setDescription(description);
    }
  else if (startDay !== endDay){
    eventCal.createAllDayEvent("Test", new Date(startDay), new Date(endDay)).setDescription(description);
  }

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you already know how to create the Google Calendar event but you want to know how to read if a Sheet has been approved or not, correct?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comment. 
what i want to do is, when a superior approves a document in Google Sheet, , i want to make a scheule only the approved document in Google Calendar. However, currently, the script I've created is making the alll of the spreadsheets that are not approved documents to the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific way to find out if a Spreadsheet has been approved or not as there is no property that containing that specific piece of information.

Managing approvals directly through the API is currently a feature request that can be found in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/208025958). However there is a workaround that someone has found to know if a file has been approved or not by reading if it has been "locked".

After a spreadsheet gets approved it automatically gets "locked" if the user did not lock it before requesting the approval. You can read the value from this property using the Drive API and use it to create a conditional to know if the file has been approved or not.

Translated to code it would look something like this:

```js
function goCreate() {
  const fileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var param = {
    fields : "contentRestrictions/reason" 
  };
  var approval = Drive.Files.get(fileId, param);
  for(var i=0; i<approval.contentRestrictions.length; i++)
  {
    if(approval.contentRestrictions[i].reason == "Locked for File Approval")
    {
      const calID = ""; // 
      var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calID);                       

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var startDay = ss.getRange("D13").getValue();            //
      var endDay = ss.getRange("G13").getValue();              // 
      var members = ss.getRange("C8:C10").getValues();         // 
      var location = ss.getRange("D14").getValue();            // 
      var description = ss.getRange("D16").getValues();        // 

      if (startDay == endDay){
        eventCal.createAllDayEvent("Test", new Date(startDay)).setDescription(description);
      }
      else if (startDay !== endDay){
        eventCal.createAllDayEvent("Test", new Date(startDay), new Date(endDay)).setDescription(description);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Just note that this may not work if a user locks the file before it has been approved.

In addition to this, there is also no way to run this script automatically after the file gets approved since there is no trigger that can recognize this kind of changes.

Please also remember that you need to add the Drive API to your script in the list of advanced services before using the script.

#### References:

- [Apps Script > Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Google Drive API > Files > Content restrictions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#:%7E:text=contentRestrictions%5B%5D.reason)
- [Apps Script > Enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)